# Character with longest consecutive repetition

Tags: javascript, arrays

i think i have wirtten the correct code for the problem only one thing and it that i return the first longest sequence how can i alter that to return the last maximum sequence?

an example from codewars editor :
for input '00000000000000111111111111111112222222222222223333333333333344444444444445555555555555666666666666777777777777888888888888888999999999999999999aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooopppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssttttttttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'

- Expected: ['c', 19], instead got: ['0', 19]

here is my code:

```
function longestRepetition(s) {

 var count = 0;
 var temp = s.charAt(0);
  var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (temp === s.charAt(i)) {
      count++
      temp = s.charAt(i)
       }
      else {
      temp = s.charAt(i);
      arr.push(count)
      count = 1;
       }
   if(i==s.length-1)
    arr.push(count);
    }
   if(arr.length>0)
   {  
    var Max=arr[0]
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(Max<=arr[i]) 
      Max=arr[i];
   }
    }

  else var Max=0;
    var mindex=arr.indexOf(Max);

 return [s.charAt(mindex),Max]

    }
```

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of the input and expected output that's not working as expected?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: There's no easy rewrite here, and your code snippet wouldn't work if the matching character appears earlier in the string as a shorter sequence. Instead of storing the character (`Max`), try storing the index of the start of the sequence.

Comment: How are you getting ['0', 19] when your input only has 14 consecutive zeros?

Comment: The last longest sequence looks to be `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, which is 19 `x`s. Shouldn't that be the desired output?

Comment: Properly indenting code is the first step in writing code that is easy to understand and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that `minindex` is an index in your `arr`, but that index has nothing to do with `s`. So `s.charAt(minindex)` makes no sense. You should maintain for which character you had found the count. For instance you could push in `arr` *both* the count and the corresponding character (as a subarray with two values). Then the rest of your code would only need little modification to make it work.

Applying this idea to your code without changing anything else, we get this:

```js
function longestRepetition(s) {
    var count = 0;
    var temp = s.charAt(0);
    var arr = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (temp === s.charAt(i)) {
            count++
            temp = s.charAt(i) // Not necessary: was already equal
        }
        else {
            arr.push([temp, count]); // <--- pair, BEFORE changing temp
            temp = s.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
        if(i==s.length-1)
            arr.push([temp, count]); // <---
    }

    if(arr.length>0)
    {  
        var Max=arr[0]; // <-- Max is now a pair of char & count
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(Max[1]<arr[i][1])  // Comparison changed to just less-than
                Max=arr[i];
        }
    }
    else Max=[null, 0]; // Must be a pair here also

    return Max; // Just return the pair
}

console.log(longestRepetition('00000000000000111111111111111112222222222222223333333333333344444444444445555555555555666666666666777777777777888888888888888999999999999999999aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooopppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssttttttttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'));
```

But you can do the same with less code:

```js
function longestRepetition(s) {
    let result = [null, 0]; // pair of character and count
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; null) {
        let start = i++;
        while (i < s.length && s[i] === s[start]) i++; // Find end of series
        if (i - start > result[1]) result = [s[start], i - start];
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(longestRepetition('00000000000000111111111111111112222222222222223333333333333344444444444445555555555555666666666666777777777777888888888888888999999999999999999aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooopppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssttttttttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be easier with a regular expression. Match any character, then backreference that character as many times as you can.

Then, you'll have an array of all the sequential sequences, eg `['000', 'aaaaa']`. Map each string to its length and pass into `Math.max`, and you'll know how long the longest sequence is.

Lastly, filter the sequences by those which have that much length, and return the last item in the filtered array:

```js
function longestRepetition(s) {
  const repeatedChars = s.match(/(.)\1*/g);
  const longestLength = Math.max(...repeatedChars.map(str => str.length));
  const longestChars = repeatedChars.filter(str => str.length === longestLength);
  return [longestChars.pop(), longestLength];
}

console.log(longestRepetition('00000000000000111111111111111112222222222222223333333333333344444444444445555555555555666666666666777777777777888888888888888999999999999999999aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooopppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssttttttttttttuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'));
```

Comment: For those of us learning the basics of regular expressions, could you break down how `/(.)\1*/g` works?

Comment: Like the answer says, it matches any character (with the `.`), then backreferences it (matches it again) as many times as possible - the `\1` is the backreference for the group that was just captured in the parentheses, and `*` repeats the previous token 0 or more times, as many times as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below answers the question with O(n) runtime:

```
function longestRepetition(s) {

    let count = s.length > 0 ? 1 : 0
    let char = s.length > 0 ? s[0] : ''

    for (let string_i = 0; string_i < s.length - 1; string_i += 1) {

        // keep track of current_char
        let current_char = s[string_i]
        let next_char = s[string_i + 1]
        
        // while the next char is same as current_char
        let tracker = 1

        while (current_char === next_char) {

            // add one to tracker
            tracker += 1
            string_i += 1
            next_char = s[string_i + 1]
        }

        // if tracker greater than count
        if (tracker > count) {

            // returned char = current char
            // count =tracker
            count = tracker;
            char = current_char;
        }
    }
    return [char, count]
}
console.log(longestRepetition("bbbaaabaaaa"))//, ["a",4]
```